# How to get this text flowing properly around floats in IE7

Tags: css, internet-explorer-7

See markup + css below, or this fiddle:
http://jsfiddle.net/gq9w6/15/  ... in IE7 (or IE8/9 compatibility view)

The "Lorem ipsum" text should be wrapping around both divs #1 and #3, but in IE7, it clears div #1.

How can I get IE7 to behave in this scenario?

HTML:

```
<div id="div1">Feature image</div>
<div id="div2">
    <div id="div4" class="a">fb like</div>
    <div id="div5" class="a">g-plus1</div>
    <div id="div5" class="a">tweet</div>
</div>
<div id="div3">related topics list</div>
<div id="div7">bi-line</div>
<p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.</p>
```

CSS:

```
#div1{border:1px dotted green;float:left;width:100px;height:100px;}
#div2{height:15px;}
#div3{float:right;clear:both;width:100px;height:30px;border:1px dotted green;}
.a{float:left;width:70px;border:1px dotted red;}
#div7{text-align:left;}
```

**UPDATE:**
HTML/CSS and fiddle to (/14) all updated with sample text that shows the purpsoe of each div.

**UPDATE**
Written description of requirements:

- A featured image floated to the left
- A series of social-media share buttons to the right of the image, in a horizontal row with the top of the row aligned with the top the featured image
- a by-line beneath the social-media buttons (they're not wrapping correctly in the fiddle,  but never mind, that's easy to fix)
- A "related topics" widget floated right, clearing the featured image (top edge of the former aligned with the bottom edge of the latter)
- article text beginning beneath the by-line, wrapping around the rest of the featured image as well as the related topics widget

Comment: I'm not sure I understand what you are trying to accomplish as your question and your fiddle do not match at all. Where is div7 supposed to be, and divs 4,5, and 6? I believe I know what you want, but clarification would really help.

Comment: Look at it in IE7 (or ie8/compatibility) and then *any* other browser. The difference in the way the text wraps is crystal clear. I updated the fiddle to this one: http://jsfiddle.net/gq9w6/15/, with sample text that give a hint to the purpose of each section

Comment: Thanks. That helps considerably. Let me look at this and I'll help with a solution and explanation. :)

Answer (score 1):

In your code `#div1` is floated to the left which takes out of the document flow, leaving `#div2` to occupy the space, although the contents is being pushed by the float. Your `#div3` is actually clearing all floats and is floated to the right (it's the reason it's on the same level as the bottom of `#div1`. Not sure what `#div7` is doing. Is it also supposed to float?

What are you trying to achieve?

If you add `float: left` to `#div2` and `#div7` and remove `clear: both` from `#div3` you will get the same result in all browsers.

Comment: I am trying to achieve this: text flow in IE7 should be the same as in other browsers, just as the question title states -- I'm not sure how to make that any clearer. Have you looked at it in IE7 or IE8/9+incompatibility view?? The word wrapping is quite different.

Comment: [The example](http://jsfiddle.net/gq9w6/21/) I provided does make it appear the same in all browsers. But then I don't understand what you're trying to achieve in terms of layout, Faust.

Comment: +1 for effort. However, you did this by removing the clear on the "related topics" widget (div 3), which I need. I've written this and other requirements more explicitly in an update to the question. Thanks - Faust.